# CSS class inheritance

Tags: css, inheritance, styles, less

font awesome css style allows to create loader wheel. 
e.g. adding these classes  fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw.
However I'd like to have my-spinner class in our project styles that would inherit from all above.
So in our project we'd add only one class to element to get spinner not 5 all the time.
We are using Less. Is there a way to define one class that will inherit from all these 5?

Thanks

Stan

Comment: See ["Extend"](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature).

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the FontAwesome CSS as LESS. (Don't forget to set the route of the fonts.)

LESS:

```
@import (less) "../css/font-awesome.min.css";

.spinner-cog {
  &:extend(.fa, .fa-spin, .fa-3x, .fa-fw);
  &:before {
    &:extend(.fa-cog:before);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<i class="spinner-cog"></i>
```

CodePen example: https://codepen.io/davidtovt/pen/QvJzjy

Comment: *You need to use Font Awesome LESS* - in opposite, you'll have to use CSS version of FA because in Less version most of these classes are defined as `.@{fa-css-prefix}-cog ...` the `extend` won't work with. More over you'll need `extend all` since most of these styles are actually `:before` selectors,

Comment: CSS as LESS. When included simply CSS, not working the `extend` in the .less file.

Comment: [Fixed codepen](https://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/pPQqGW?editors=1100) (It's not that the one in the answer is incorrect but it's a bit confusing if it does not actually show any icons).